# Switch ContentView.Content, using a Bindable Property, AKA ContentView to ContentView Navigation in Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

As outlined in the 30th post below, by ClintStLaurent

EDIT: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85773/how-to-create-a-static-header

it's possible to have a permanent navigational bar ( the NavigationalPage is Placed on each indivual page, and is stored and rendered unnecessarily when changing between pages).

This is achieved by having your mainpage as a ContentPage and then inclduing a ContentView with the property Content as binded (as ContentView.Content is bindable).

I have this all set up in my code, but I can not seem to get it to work.
Any help or even a point in the right direction for further reading would be a massive help.

Comment: `As outlined in the 30th post here, by ClintStLaurent` <-- how about you post a link to that instead. It won't stay as the 30th post for long

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out